# Build tool for Powershell Projects?

Tags: software-development, software-testing, powershell, build-tool

I have a large Powershell project that feels big enough to require a build environment, unit testing, etc... but I also eat my own dog food, so, it would be nice to be able to use it at the same time I'm developing it.

I'm looking for an `ant` or `maven` or `msbuild` or `make` type tool to do this.

So far I have found [psake](https://psake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which from what I can tell seems quite similar to `ant`, but before digging in, I wanted to make sure there wasn't something better; maybe with dependency management.